# C program - weird Seg fault in dynamic programming algorithm

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a program in C to do a simple dynamic programming algorithm where you return the minimum number of coins needed to add up to a certain amount. Here's my code:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
This function returns the minimum number of stamps required for a given value.
It assumes that the given array contains the available stamp sizes, and that it
always contains 1, so a solution is always possible
*/
int min_number_of_stamps(const int* array, size_t array_size, int request) {

    /* Construct a table with dimensions (array_size+1)*(request+1) */ 
    int numRows = array_size + 1;
    int numCols = request + 1;
    int **DPtable; 
    DPtable = malloc(numRows*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        DPtable[i] = malloc(numCols*sizeof(int));
    }
    printf("%d",DPtable[4][0]);
    int r, c, useIt, loseIt;
    for (r = 0; r < numRows; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < numCols; c++) {
            printf("%d,%d\n", r, c);
            if (c==0) {
                printf("1\n");
                //if the amount of change is 0, 0 coins are needed 
                DPtable[r][c] = 0;
            } 
            else if ((r==0) || c < array[r-1]) {
                printf("2\n");
                //if there are no coins or if the change needed is less than 
                //the smallest coin available, then 'infinity' coins are needed
                DPtable[r][c] = INT_MAX;
            } 
            else { 
                printf("3\n");
                useIt = DPtable[r][c-array[r-1]] + 1;
                loseIt = DPtable[r-1][c];
                if (useIt <= loseIt) { 
                    //if 'use it' requires fewer coins than 'lose it,' then 
                    //'use it' coins are needed. 
                    DPtable[r][c] = useIt;
                } 
                else { 
                    //if 'lose it' requires fewer coins, 'lose it' coins are needed 
                    DPtable[r][c] = loseIt; 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return DPtable[numRows][numCols];

}

int main() {
    const int array[] = {1,5,10,25};
    const int* stamps = &array[0];
    printf("%d", min_number_of_stamps(stamps, 4, 44));
}
```

I'm getting a segfault when my inner for loop gets to the case where r=4 and c=0. I left my debugging print statements in because I'm lazy, but you can see where I got stuck. If I access the same place in the array outside of my for loops, there's no problem. But in the for loop, I get a `Segmentation fault: 11' message after it outputs "4,0" for the array element and "1" for the if case it's in. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allocating `dpTable` incorrectly. It should be

```
DPtable = malloc(numRows*sizeof(int*));
```

See if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Ugh, that was totally it. I've never been able to keep all the pointer stuff straight

Comment: This could be it, if its a 64bit system a sizeof(int*) is 8 while sizeof(int) might be 4.

Answer (score 3):

Learn to enable warnings & debugging for your compiler, i.e. `gcc -g -Wall` on Linux.

Learn to use a debugger, i.e. `gdb -tui` on Linux.

Consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

**EDIT** 
Many tutorials (in several languages, e.g. English, French, ....) for GCC, GDB, and ValGrind are easily found on the Web.

Comment: I don't have a C debugger set up on my home machine. If you're going to just tell me to learn something, at least link to a beginner's tutorial, or else don't bother answering.

Comment: Without a debugger you (and every C programmer) is in trouble. But `valgrind` could have helped you.

Comment: I'm not a C programmer. I just had to do this one problem in C.

Comment: Don't program in C if you don't want to. It is a difficult and painful language. Try e.g. to code in Ocaml; the compiler will help you much more, and your Ocaml program won't crash if it compiles.

Comment: @Basile: Yes, C is very difficult and painful, I generally avoid it, but occasionally I am forced to do something using it, like in this case. Sorry my first comment was so nasty, I just get frustrated when I'm trying to figure out something I will never have to do again, and I get told to essentially become and expert in the area.

Comment: Yes, you need to somehow "become expert in C" to successfully program in C. Actually, you need more to understand the semantics of C (which is essentially an abstract processor ...) than to just understand its syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`return DPtable[numRows][numCols];`

thats out of bounds isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it is, but the code doesn't even get to that point, so fixing that didn't help.

Comment: Why? The allocated dimensions are (numRows+1, numCols+1).

Comment: No, not in the code you are showing us. there the dimensions are  numRows * numCols.. also known as  (array_size + 1) * (request + 1)

Comment: Martin, I just re-read the code, and you are of course correct about the bounds. I must have had a faulty parser the first time through ;-)